# Accessing javascript variable in jsp in java

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, openlayers

I have included my javascript file in head of jsp file! What i want that there is a variable which is increasing everyone using click on the map, and i want that value in the jsp page. Please tell me how to do that, here is my code!

The JSP file code! incremental value i is defined is ClickHandler.js

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="ClickHandler.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<h1>This is login Page</h1>

<body onload='init();'>


<form action="helloWelcome" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="surname">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<div id="Map" style="height: 650px" ></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my ClickHandler.js file code!

```
var i=0;

var map,vectorLayer, selectedFeature;
           var lat=33.7167;
            var lon=73.0667;
            var zoom=10;
            var map;
        var curpos = new Array();
        var position;

            var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
            var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection

            var cntrposition       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

        function init()
        {
                map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map",{
                            controls: 
                            [
                                        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),                        
                            new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}),
                            new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                            new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({}),
                            new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                            new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),
                                    ]
                              }
                                );
                var mapnik      = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("MAP"); 

            map.addLayers([mapnik]);
            //map.addLayer(mapnik);
            map.setCenter(cntrposition, zoom);

            //markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(cntrposition));

            var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
            map.addControl(click);

            click.activate();
};

OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {               
 defaultHandlerOptions: {
  'single': true,
  'double': false,
  'pixelTolerance': 0,
  'stopSingle': false,
  'stopDouble': false
 },

 initialize: function(options) {
  this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
   {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
  );
  OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
   this, arguments
  );
  this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
   this, {
    'click': this.trigger
   }, this.handlerOptions
  );
 },

 trigger: function(e) {
  var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
  lonlat1= new OpenLayers.LonLat(lonlat.lon,lonlat.lat).transform(toProjection,fromProjection);
  var long_value=lonlat1.lon;
  var lat_value=lonlat1.lat;
  //action=""
  i=i+1;
  alert("ur coordinates ..."+i+" "+long_value + "  " +lat_value);

  //<a href="login.jsp"><a>
  //<link href="login.jsp" >
 }
});
```

Comment: You can do something like this _<script>
var v="xyz";
</script>
<% String st="<script>document.writeln(v)</script>";
out.println("value="+st); %>_

Comment: What do you mean, you "... want that value in the JSP page ..." ? You are aware that the JSP will have all finished running before the user starts clicking on stuff, right?

Comment: I want to get the value of "i" in servlet when user click on the JSP page, but my "i" variable is defined in .js file which is icnluded in the head of jsp file. @DavidWallace

Comment: What do you want to do with the value of `i`?  The servlet has finished running, when the user clicks on the JSP page.  So it doesn't make sense to say you want to get it in the servlet.

Comment: i really appreciate your help. actually when ever user click on the map which i loaded in jsp using java script file which has open layers code, the value of i goes on inreasing and i want to know that user has clicked how much times on the map when he press submit button on jsp file . this us why i need that value of "i".

Comment: So you want to submit that value in the form?  Sure.  What you need is a hidden field, and Javascript that sets the value of the field.  Give the field a name that will let you pick it up in the servlet.

Comment: yes this is what i want. Can you help me regarding hidden field according to my code,  actually i tried few statements but it did not work. plz help me about this hidden field  thing.. thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/Usehiddenfieldtostoredata.htm